# How do I access variables from the main class from another class in the same project?

Tags: java, class, variables, program-entry-point

I'm making a cookie clicker clone in java to practice my java skills and I have a small problem, I have variables that are declared in the main class that I want to access from an ActionListener class. Here is some sample code from the ActionListener class. the the int variables (ex. clicks, grandamaCost) and the JTextFields (ex. display, cpsDisplay) are all in the main class. I was wondering how I could have access to variables in the main class so that this code could work in the other class. Thanks!

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    button(b.getText());
}

/**
 *
 * @param input the label of the buttons being clicked.
 */
public void button(String input) {
    switch (input) {
        case "Cookie":
            clicks++;
            display.setText("Cookies: " + clicks + "");
            cpsDisplay.setText("CPS: " + cps);
            break;
        case "Buy grandma":
            if (clicks >= grandmaCost) {
                grandmas++;
                clicks = clicks - grandmaCost;
                grandmaCost = (int) ((.15 * grandmaCost) + grandmaCost);
                cps++;
            }
            display.setText("Cookies: " + clicks + "");
            prices[0].setText("$" + grandmaCost);
            cpsDisplay.setText("CPS: " + cps);
            break;
        case "Buy monkey":
            if (clicks >= monkeyCost) {
                monkeys++;
                clicks = clicks - monkeyCost;
                monkeyCost = (int) ((.15 * monkeyCost) + monkeyCost);
                cps = cps + 2;
            }
            display.setText("Cookies: " + clicks + "");
            prices[1].setText("$" + monkeyCost);
            cpsDisplay.setText("CPS: " + cps);
            break;
        case "Buy Teemo":
            if (clicks >= teemoCost) {
                teemos++;
                clicks = clicks - teemoCost;
                teemoCost = (int) ((.15 * teemoCost) + teemoCost);
                cps = cps + 3;
            }
            display.setText("Cookies: " + clicks + "");
            prices[2].setText("$" + teemoCost);
            cpsDisplay.setText("CPS: " + cps);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416446/how-do-i-access-variables-from-the-main-class-from-another-class-java

Comment: You asked this question already.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt actually go via your code, but standard way to do this is you define two private class variables in your main class

```
private int clicks
```

then you define setters and getters to set them and get them

```
public int getClicks() {
     return clicks;
}

public int setClicks(int i) {
      clicks = i;
}
```

Then you use the above methods to get and set to use it out side any class