# How can I get data generated by one function in one class in another class in same package in java

Tags: java

now I have a package in my current project with 2 java classes. One of them pull data from a table and rearrange into a `Map`. The other class does the checking work in which it need access this `Map` frequently. Obviously, I don't want to generate this `Map` every time the checking class called. What is the easiest and most efficient way for me to store that `Map`  making my checking class work faster. I hope to find a way to make that Map global accessible within my package after it is generated. Need advice!

To make it clear, the checking class extend abstract class of a spark UDF1. So it will work as a UDF on spark. No main function in both classes, THx.

Comment: What do you mean with 2 java programs? Are there two .jar files or classes?

Comment: make the map static.. Make it load only once and reuse in other places

Comment: I don't think that package sharing between 2 *programs* is a good idea or I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: @Blobonat edited, 2 classes.

Comment: do you have 2 classes with the main method in each one?

Comment: @BhargavKumarR static map in class can be accessed in other class?

Comment: @G_cy Ofcourse..Yes

Comment: @BhargavKumarR my 2 classes are in different .java file. I tried but not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access variables from the main class from another class (java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416446/how-do-i-access-variables-from-the-main-class-from-another-class-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correct.. It is like below

```
public class Loader {

    public static Map<K, V> holder;

    public void loadMap() {
        // Code to populate map goes here
    }
}
```

and you will be able to access map like

```
public class Checker {

    public void check() {
        // Acccess map like this Loader.holder;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made that map private then I failed, how dumb.... You are right and thank you for help, really.